# console error : Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') every time page reloads

Tags: jquery

So I've searched for ages and can't find anything to solve this problem with. I have a function for a modal that will show a YouTube video and everything works fine with the modal and the video.

But every time my webpage reloads and if I go to another page on the site I get this error message in the console `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"`. I've think that my script is trying to run even though I've haven't clicked the modal to open? I've tried adding `$(window).load(function(){}` function. But that did not solve the problem.

Does anyone know how I can fix it or show me in the right direction?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   const close = document.querySelector('#close');
   const open = document.querySelector('#open');
   const modal_container = document.querySelector('#modal-container');
   var url = $('#seaspiracy').attr('src');

   $(window).load(function(){
     open.addEventListener('click', () => {
         modal_container.classList.add('show');
         $('#seaspiracy').attr('src', url);
         $("#seaspiracy").attr('src', url + "?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0" ); 

     });

     close.addEventListener('click', () => {
         modal_container.classList.remove('show');
         $('#seaspiracy').attr('src', '');
     });
   });
});
```

```html
<section class="mst-section" id="about-section">
   <div class="mst-row">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="mst-column-1">
            <div class="mst-inner-column">
               <div class="about-img-box">
                  <div class="about-img"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="about-text-box">
                  <div class="about-text">
                     <h2></h2>
                     <p>
                        <span class="about-seaspiracy"><button id="open">Seaspiracy</button></span> 
                     </p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-container" id="modal-container">
      <iframe id="seaspiracy" class="modal" loading="lazy" width="600" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1Q5CXN7soQg" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <button class="modal-close-btn" id="close">X</button>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you share HTML code?

Comment: Yes, I have added the HTML code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

When the document is ready, the load event of the page is already triggered. I think this is the cause of the problem. Therefore I removed the `load` event; in this case I didn't get any error warnings and the old behaviors continued to work.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var url = $('#seaspiracy').attr('src');
    
    $('#open').click(function() {
      $('#modal_container').addClass('show');
      $('#seaspiracy').attr('src', url);
      $("#seaspiracy").attr('src', url + "?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0" );
    });

    $('#close').click(function() {
        $('#modal_container').removeClass('show');
        $('#seaspiracy').attr('src', '');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="mst-section" id="about-section">
<div class="mst-row">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="mst-column-1">
         <div class="mst-inner-column">
            <div class="about-img-box">
               <div class="about-img"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="about-text-box">
               <div class="about-text">
                  <h2></h2>
                  <p>
                      <span class="about-seaspiracy"><button id="open">Seaspiracy</button></span> 
                  </p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-container" id="modal-container">
   <iframe id="seaspiracy" class="modal" loading="lazy" width="600" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1Q5CXN7soQg" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   <button class="modal-close-btn" id="close">X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Okey I see. I still getting the error message even if the load function is removed. Do you know if there is a way to have the script to wait to run?

Comment: The `$(document).ready()` method allows specifying events that will run after the DOM is loaded. I don't understand what you are trying to do. I've updated the app to be jQuery compatible so I can catch errors.

Comment: The problem may also be that you define items using `const`. You must not change the element defined with `const`.